# How can i add color label of each edge in networkx in python

Tags: python, networkx

[My networkx graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q60kS.png)

In my directed networkx graph , i have drawn edges color based on weight. I am able to add them as labels in my graph but it is appearing twice. How can i add edges label with different color only once along with directions

```
`elarge=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] >0.10]
emed=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] >0.05 and d['weight'] <0.10]
esmall=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <0.05]

# red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label= "Probablity < 0.05")
# plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])

# blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Probablity > 0.10')
# plt.legend(handles=[blue_patch])

# green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green',label='Probablity > 0.15 and Probablity < 0.10')
# plt.legend(handles=[green_patch])


pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # positions for all nodes
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=4000,node_color= "grey")

# edges

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=elarge,
                    width=2,alpha = 0.6,edge_color = "b",label = "Probablity > 0.10",arrows=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=esmall,
                    width=3,alpha=0.6,edge_color='r',label = "Probablity < 0.05",arrows=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=emed,
                    width=3,alpha=0.6,edge_color='g',label = "'Probablity > 0.15 and Probablity < 0.10'",arrows=True)

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, labels = edge_labels,arrows=False)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels1,font_size=12,font_family='sans-serif')
plt.legend(numpoints = 1)
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the code to generate your network and please put the image for your network in the actual question itself.

Comment: I think your concern is the fact that the label is appearing twice in the legend, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

To me, this looks like a bug in networkx (still present in 1.11).  Looking at the [source code](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.11/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_edges) for `draw_networkx_edges`, it creates the edges, and then it creates the arrowheads as thicker lines.

After creating the edges, there is the command `edge_collection.set_label(label)`, which sets the labels for the edges.  But after creating the arrowheads it also has `arrow_collection.set_label(label)`.  So both the edge and the arrowhead end up labelled in the legend (this is why you'll see that in your legend the labels appear with two associated widths).

I believe it would be enough to go to the networkx code on your computer and simply comment out `arrow_collection.set_label(label)`.  Another alternative would be to draw the edge without the arrowheads and give it a label, and then redraw it (using the same color) with an arrowhead but no label.

I've submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2503) on this, as I can't think of any reason why one would want a separate label for the arrowhead.